# Ratchet Framework scrolling in Android 2.2

Tags: android, css, cordova, ratchet-2

Im using Ratchet Framework for andriod app development.
I have some scrolling problems in some android phones and also in bluestack.
when scrolled, a toomany blank spaces occurs and it affects the smooth scrolling. also affects the forms in the page. attached the image related[image]

scrolling on some other devices is good , No extra space.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) make sure you are using the meta tags provided by ratchet.

2) make sure you are inserting the bar-tab navigation at the top right after the body

From the ratchet [getting started guide](http://goratchet.com/getting-started/):

**1. Fixed bars come first**

All fixed bars (.bar) should always be the first thing in the  of the page. This is really important!

**2. Everything else goes in .content**

Anything that's not a .bar should be put in a div with the class .content. Put this div after the bars in the  tag. The .content div is what actually scrolls in a Ratchet prototype.

**3. Don't forget your meta tags**

They're included in the template.html page included in the download, but make sure they stay in the page. They are important to Ratchet working just right.

If that doesn't help post some code and let us take a look at it